# How to write a parametrized query in management studio?

Tags: sql-server, parameters, ssms

From a client application I tyipically do:

```
select * from table where Name = :Parameter
```

and then before executing the query I do

```
:Parameter = 'John'
```

These parameters are not a Search&Replace but real parameters passed to the server. Since I need to test some of those queries in detail, how can I write the query in management studio?

I want to write the query with parameters and give a value to the parameter. How can this be done?

**Update:**

To remove confusion here I add info to better express myseld.

when I execute a normal query I see in sql server profiler

```
select * from table where Name = 'John'
```

while when I execute a parametrized query I see this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select * from table 
where Name = @P1',N'@P1 varchar(8000)','John'
```

This is why I say it is not a search and replace.

Comment: The update does pretty much what I showed you in my Answer...

Comment: Ok you are right. So what I got is that when a client application uses parameters somehow it decalres variables with DELCARE. Very interesting, this helps in solving a problem I have.

Comment: To explain you why I asked this question I redirect you to my final question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408551/select-statment-performance-degradation-when-using-distinct-with-parameters

Answer (score 44, accepted):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @Parameter VARCHAR(20)
SET @Parameter = 'John'

SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Name = @Parameter
```

Comment: No this is "Serach and replace", in this way I am not telling sql_server that it is a parameter.

Comment: Please see my Update to the question so yuo get what i mean.

Comment: This answer can actually run with a different execution plan than the code as SQL Server is able to optimize the plan for the 'John' value

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you answered your own question when you updated it.

Rewriting here for future visitors who may be confused like I was. Below is how you write a parameterized query in SSMS. This helps if you want to analyze the execution plan for a parameterized query run by your code.

```
EXEC sp_executesql
N'

SELECT * FROM table_t 
WHERE first_name = @parameter

',
N'@parameter VARCHAR(8000)',
N'John'
```

Comment: this missed the multi-parameter query case. I was assuming, wrongly, you have to add more parameters to SP... This also misses quotes in string values.  How about an exmple using a couple of date/time and a couple of text parameters (with commas and maybe quotes) at once, to highlight hard aspects? P.S. it is indeed so weird SMS still cannot just do params....

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Adriaan Stander's answer, if you were using C# in your code for example, you should have ensured that you have passed the `@parameter`via encapsulating. Here is a code example:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(userSql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter", parameter);


    conn.Close();

}
```

This code is intended to give you an idea and therefore isn't complete.

Comment: This answer contradicts question tags.  It's true but irrelevant if using SSMS.