# SQL DEVELOPER Dynamic table

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL and i created a query has which has to display a table with many filtering.
so I created Query like this one;

```
*-- input--
select CountryID, COUNT([Document name]) as inputcount ,
MONTH([Creation Date]) AS [Creation Month],Year([Creation Date]) as [Creation Year] INTO TEMP
from dbo.ggg` `
WHERE  [doc_type_product_type] not in ('CUST')
and [Document_Source] in ('FAX','Original') 
AND ([Monto en Dolares test]  > 0 or [Monto en Dolares test]  = null) 
group by [CountryID],MONTH([Creation Date]) ,Year([Creation Date]) order by [CountryID];*
```

And every this is fine with this query, but in case new filters show up then i don't have to make alteration to this query or script. So i think there is a way where i can store the filters and pass them to my query and in case of alteration or update i can do it on the table. Any suggestions.

Comment: My 1st suggestion is to stop using all caps when writing your question.

Comment: What is the question here? It is like reading a stream of consciousness. There is nothing coherent in the question at all. What are you actually asking here??

Comment: Paremeterized query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407070/how-to-write-a-parametrized-query-in-management-studio or https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/?

Comment: The solution you are looking for is called a [VIEW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql)

Comment: Hello my question is  in case i have new filter in the [Document_Source] Field  how this new filter  to the existing query , without making alteration to the query it self since i have a lot of queries. so the question is there should be  way where i can store my filters in one place or table and then i can pass these filters to the existing queries? --Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think [Bartosz X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5243515/bartosz-x) is correct, the easiest way to maintain (new/old) filters is to probably build a view and use the 'Filter' column in design. That way you do not have to directly edit the query.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. I will try your recommendations